# Access part of a row very quickly in Pandas

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I'm doing 20 billion calculations, and it turns out that the slowest step by two orders of magnitude is just accessing the relevant rows in a Pandas dataframe.

```
%timeit x = query_results.ix[i]
10000 loops, best of 3: 155 µs per loop
```

How can we drop that speed by one or two orders of magnitude?

This Dataframe has 200,000 rows and 11 columns, all strings of various lengths. Making the strings a fixed length barely budges the access speed. Making the values floats (which isn't feasible for this use case) would drop the speed by about half.

Edit for more context:
This is approximately the whole use case, using the suggestion of BrenBarn to use `iloc` instead of `ix`. Note that we access only two rows at a time. The large number of calculations comes from comparing every row to every other row (200,000^2/2).

```
test = pd.DataFrame(index=arange(200000),columns=arange(11))
test.ix[:,:] = 'asdfasdf'

i = 0
j = 1

%timeit x = set(test.iloc[i]).intersection(test.iloc[j])
1000 loops, best of 3: 235 µs per loop
```

It would be fantastic if that number could be more like 5µs.

Side note, as an example of why every µs counts: Not every cell actually contains data, so I still need to remove missing values (`nan`) from the resulting data, which will take more µs. Doing something like `test.iloc[i].dropna()` is very slow for these purposes.

Comment: What kind of indexing are you doing?  You may be able to get a speedup by using `.iloc` or `.loc`, but it depends on how you're indexing (with a single index label, a single numerical index, a list of either of these, etc.).  Also, doing this indexing creates a new DataFrame, so if you're selecting a large number of rows, it will be slow (since it has to create a big DataFrame).  How to optimize this depends on what you're doing with the result.

Comment: Agree some more details would be helpful, if you're pulling out single values `.iat` or `.at` may provide some speed up.

Comment: Edited above for more context.

Comment: Why are you use indexing on the underlying data, e.g. ``df.values``? you don't seem to be using any of pandas indexing features. using an indexer is NOT meant for repeated access like you are doing (as their is a lot of validation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [21]: tx = test.values

In [22]: tx
Out[22]: 
array([['asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf', ..., 'asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf',
        'asdfasdf'],
       ['asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf', ..., 'asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf',
        'asdfasdf'],
       ['asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf', ..., 'asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf',
        'asdfasdf'],
       ..., 
       ['asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf', ..., 'asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf',
        'asdfasdf'],
       ['asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf', ..., 'asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf',
        'asdfasdf'],
       ['asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf', ..., 'asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf',
        'asdfasdf']], dtype=object)

In [23]: %timeit x = set(tx[i]).intersection(tx[j])
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.99 µs per loop
```

Comment: yep. keep in mind that on a mixed dtype frame this is a non-trivial operation (the ``.values``, so don't do it in a loop)